# MemSQL for Last n Days Data

Tags: singlestore

I plan to use memsql to store my last 7 days data for real time analytics using SQL.

I checked the documentation and find out that there is no such TTL / expiration feature in MemSQL

- Is there any such feature (in case I missed it)?
- Is memsql fit the use case if I do daily delete on >7 days data? I quite curious about the fragmentation

We tried it on postgresql and we need to execute Vacuum command, it takes a long time to run.

Answer (score 0):

There is no TTL/expiration feature. You can do it by running delete queries. Many customer use cases are doing this type of thing, so yes MemSQL does fit the use case. Fragmentation generally shouldn't be too much of a problem here - what kind of fragmentation are you concerned about?

Answer (score 0):

There is No Out of the Box TTL feature in MemSQL.

We achieved TTL by adding an additional TS column in our MemSQL Rowstore table with TIMESTAMP(6) datatype.

This provides automatic current timestamp insertion when you add a new row to the table.

When querying data from this table, you can apply a simple filter based on this TIMESTAMP column to filter older records beyond your TTL value.

https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.7/datatypes/#time-and-date

You can always have a batch job which can run one a month which can delete older data.

we have not seen any issues due to fragmentation but you can do below once in a while if fragmentation is a concern for you:

MemSQL’s memory allocators can become fragmented over time (especially if a large table is shrunk dramatically by deleting data randomly). **There is no command currently available that will compact them, but running ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX followed by ALTER TABLE DROP INDEX will do it.**

**Warning**
Caution should be taken with this work around. Plans will rebuild and the two ALTER queries are going to move all moves in the table twice, so this should not be used that often.

Reference:
https://docs.memsql.com/troubleshooting/latest/troubleshooting/